# Spot light looks fine in the viewport, but when I render the result is different

Tags: rendering, light

In my viewport, I see my spot light shows fine.

[image]

But when I hit render, the spot light doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the spot light works, (the top left of the card shows the spot light), but probably you have one or more lights that are disabled for viewing (eye icon in the outliner) but not for rendering (camera icon). Or maybe the "world" is set to some value other than 0 (if what you want is a black environment)

Comment: Thanks @susu, I actually forgot to delete a couple of area lights.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I forgot to delete some area lights ‍♂️